# Can the Crystalline Entity "eat" energy?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

According to memory alpha and "Silicon Avatar," the Crystalline Entity converts organic matter into energy, and then absorbs it.

If the Entity came across a relatively weak energy creature, could it just be "sucked up," or does its "vacuum" only work on organic matter?

Comment: I don't think that this is ultimately answerable, as it requires a level of understanding of the respective biologies of two barely seen characters coincidentally colliding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is yes. In [TNG : Silicon Avatar](http://www.st-minutiae.com/academy/literature329/204.txt) the Crystalline Entity is described as functioning like...

> **...a giant electromagnetic collector.** It needs a lot of power to keep
>   going... so it strips every form of life from the worlds it encounters
>   and **converts it all into energy.**

It follows that a being that was *already* composed of the right kind of energy could be freely ingested without the need to disintegrate it first.

---

Moving down the canon scale, we see precisely this situation in the TNG book "[Orion's Hounds](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Orion's_Hounds)".

After encountering a colony of "*branchers*" (a local slang term for the Crystalline Entities), Captain Will Riker provides a race known as the Pa’haquel with a weapon based on the gravitic beam used in Silicon Avatar. He also attempts to feed them **directly from the deflector array** in the form of bio-energetic electromagnetic energy.

Ultimately, the Pa’haquel use the branchers to attack another set of creatures known as the cosmozoans, beings the size of solar systems largely comprised of energetic gases and capable of destroying entire civilisations.

Comment: It's too bad that "Silicon Avatar" didn't have a teaser scene showing the Entity consuming that jerk Armus.